# Generic method to convert a flat JSON array to nested JSON

Tags: c#, arrays, json, generics

I have a JSON object as below

```
[
  {
    "Id": 7,
    "Name": "Colocation Folder",
    "ParentId": 1,
    "depth": 0
  },
  {
    "Id": 8,
    "Name": "CoLo Real Estate",
    "ParentId": 7,
    "depth": 1
  },
  {
    "Id": 10,
    "Name": "CoLo: Burst",
    "ParentId": 7,
    "depth": 1
  },
  {
    "Id": 34,
    "Name": "CoLo Dedicated Bandwidth",
    "ParentId": 7,
    "depth": 1
  },
  {
    "Id": 10035,
    "Name": "Infrastructure as a Service",
    "ParentId": 7,
    "depth": 1
  },
  {
    "Id": 10037,
    "Name": "Software as a Service",
    "ParentId": 7,
    "depth": 1
  },
  {
    "Id": 10038,
    "Name": "IaaS Component Upgrade",
    "ParentId": 7,
    "depth": 1
  },
  {
    "Id": 668,
    "Name": "CoLo Misc Folder",
    "ParentId": 7,
    "depth": 1
  },
  {
    "Id": 758,
    "Name": "CoLo: Conduit Fee",
    "ParentId": 668,
    "depth": 2
  },
  {
    "Id": 765,
    "Name": "CoLo: Private VLAN",
    "ParentId": 668,
    "depth": 2
  }
]
```

The `Id` and `ParentId` fields show the relation between the items. I need to make it as a nested JSON using C#.
Since there will be many such models, I don't want to create individual classes for each model. Is there a generic approach in C# that will take a flat JSON array, take the `ID` and `ParentId` fields as input and then return me a nested JSON with all other fields in the array as well? For example, I am looking for an output of nested JSON as below:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 7,
    "Name": "Colocation Folder",
    "items": [
      {
        "Id": 8,
        "Name": "CoLo Real Estate",
        "ParentId": 7
      },
      {
        "Id": 10,
        "Name": "CoLo: Burst",
        "ParentId": 7
      },
      {
        "Id": 34,
        "Name": "CoLo Dedicated Bandwidth",
        "ParentId": 7
      },
      {
        "Id": 10035,
        "Name": "Infrastructure as a Service",
        "ParentId": 7
      },
      {
        "Id": 10037,
        "Name": "Software as a Service",
        "ParentId": 7
      },
      {
        "Id": 10038,
        "Name": "IaaS Component Upgrade",
        "ParentId": 7
      },
      {
        "Id": 668,
        "Name": "CoLo Misc Folder",
        "ParentId": 7,
        "items": [
          {
            "Id": 758,
            "Name": "CoLo: Conduit Fee",
            "ParentId": 668
          },
          {
            "Id": 765,
            "Name": "CoLo: Private VLAN",
            "ParentId": 668
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Give an example of your desired results.  It isn't clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the desired results. Thanks

Comment: In your example JSON, why does the root object have a `ParentId` of `1`?  What does that refer to?

Comment: Brian - It basically means that it has a parent which is not shown here. Basically, this is just like one branch in the tree.. I want only the children  to be nested based on the ParentId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), you can do this conversion in a generic way using the [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JObjects).  The idea is to parse the JSON array and add all the individual items to a dictionary keyed by `Id`.  Then, loop over the dictionary items, and for each one, try to look up the parent.  If the parent is found, add the item to the parent's `items` array (creating it if needed).  Otherwise, add the item to the `root` array.  Along the way, remove the `depth` property from each item, since you don't seem to want that in the output.  Lastly, just dump the `root` array to string to get the final result.

```
var dict = JArray.Parse(json)
    .Children<JObject>()
    .ToDictionary(jo => (string)jo["Id"], jo => new JObject(jo));

var root = new JArray();

foreach (JObject obj in dict.Values)
{
    JObject parent;
    string parentId = (string)obj["ParentId"];
    if (parentId != null && dict.TryGetValue(parentId, out parent))
    {
        JArray items = (JArray)parent["items"];
        if (items == null)
        {
            items = new JArray();
            parent.Add("items", items);
        }
        items.Add(obj);
    }
    else
    {
        root.Add(obj);
    }

    JProperty depth = obj.Property("depth");
    if (depth != null) depth.Remove();
}

Console.WriteLine(root.ToString());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Buza6T

Comment: Brian - the code works when ParentId is available but when the ParentId is null, I get an exception Can not convert Null to Int32.
and I therefore changed the dictionary to object instead of int

var dict = JArray.Parse(JSONString)
            .Children<JObject>()
            .ToDictionary(jo => (object)jo[IdFieldName], jo => new JObject(jo));

Comment: I added a fix which checks whether ParentId has a value before trying to use it.

Comment: In that case, I would just make the dictionary keys strings.  It will work for ints also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic object with JSON.Net like so to detect your properties dynamically then you could build a new json object with the desired nesting:
                using Newtonsoft.Json;
                using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

```
            dynamic d = JArray.Parse(stringy);
            foreach(var ob in d)
            {
                if(ob.ParentID != ob.Id)
                {
                    string debug = "oh snapple, it's a child object";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Share my working code for you at [jsFiddle full source code](https://jsfiddle.net/hoogw/Lsexh7dp/4/)

recursive function is:

```
  function getNestedChildren(arr, parent) {
var out = []
for(var i in arr) {
    if(arr[i].parent == parent) {
        var children = getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i].id)

        if(children.length) {
            arr[i].children = children
        }
        out.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
 return out
}
```

full source code:

```
        function getNestedChildren(arr, parent) {
        var out = []
        for(var i in arr) {
            if(arr[i].ParentId == parent) {
                var items = getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i].Id)

                if(items.length) {
                    arr[i].items = items
                }
                out.push(arr[i])
            }
        }
        return out
    }


    var flat_array = [
      {
        "Id": 7,
        "Name": "Colocation Folder",
        "ParentId": 1,
        "depth": 0
      },
      {
        "Id": 8,
        "Name": "CoLo Real Estate",
        "ParentId": 7,
        "depth": 1
      },
      {
        "Id": 10,
        "Name": "CoLo: Burst",
        "ParentId": 7,
        "depth": 1
      },
      {
        "Id": 34,
        "Name": "CoLo Dedicated Bandwidth",
        "ParentId": 7,
        "depth": 1
      },
      {
        "Id": 10035,
        "Name": "Infrastructure as a Service",
        "ParentId": 7,
        "depth": 1
      },
      {
        "Id": 10037,
        "Name": "Software as a Service",
        "ParentId": 7,
        "depth": 1
      },
      {
        "Id": 10038,
        "Name": "IaaS Component Upgrade",
        "ParentId": 7,
        "depth": 1
      },
      {
        "Id": 668,
        "Name": "CoLo Misc Folder",
        "ParentId": 7,
        "depth": 1
      },
      {
        "Id": 758,
        "Name": "CoLo: Conduit Fee",
        "ParentId": 668,
        "depth": 2
      },
      {
        "Id": 765,
        "Name": "CoLo: Private VLAN",
        "ParentId": 668,
        "depth": 2
      }
    ]


    var nested = getNestedChildren(flat_array, 1)

    console.log(nested)
```